# Raw sql query in Django rest framework with parameter

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

how to working with raw sql in django rest framework. can you help me out?

1-sql query-

```
  SELECT date, driver_id,
  sum(case when type='TRIP_ADJUSTMENT' then amount  ELSE 0 end) as TRIP_ADJUSTMENT
  from fleet_driverpenalty WHERE driver_id= %s and (date BETWEEN %s and %s)
```

2-views.py

```
  class DriverPenaltyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
      queryset= DriverPenalty.objects.all().order_by('driver_id')
      serializer_class=DriverPenaltySerializer
```

3- serializer.py

```
 class DriverPenaltySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model= DriverPenalty
         fields=('date','driver_id','type','amount')
```

Comment: Where will the parameters (`driver_id=%s` and `date between %s and %s`) originate from? From the query string? From the request body? Something else?

Comment: from query string, i need to take input from parameter and get output base on paramter for ex- driver_id= 586 and (date BETWEEN '2020-11-16' and '2020-11-22')

Comment: so what is the structure of the query string?

Comment: class DriverPenaltyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
      queryset= DriverPenalty.objects.raw(''' SELECT date, driver_id,
  sum(case when type='TRIP_ADJUSTMENT' then amount  ELSE 0 end) as TRIP_ADJUSTMENT
  from fleet_driverpenalty WHERE driver_id= %s and (date BETWEEN %s and %s)''')
      serializer_class=DriverPenaltySerializer

Comment: i am new in django